# WSS deployment

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, wss

What is the best way to deploy a heavily customized SharePoint solution from test environment into production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proper SharePoint development uses solution packages (WSP) and features. For the former, I recommend using [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) or [STSDev](http://stsdev.codeplex.com/). The latter are defined in XML ([schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414322.aspx)) with associated files, all deployed through solution packages.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your 'solution' is? Code or customisations?

If you want to move content, have a look at [SPDeploymentWizard](http://www.codeplex.com/SPDeploymentWizard)

It works miracles for me.